# UIRefreshControl weird jump when scrolling down with preferLargeTitles enabled

Tags: swift, uirefreshcontrol, preferslargetitles

My `UIRefreshControl` is not working properly when I scroll down my `collectionview`. The `refreshControl` pops out even with a slight scrolling and causes the title to jump down a bit.

I tried with:

```
extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
```

And that fixes something but still does a small jump (almost unnoticeable) when scrolling down to engage the refresh control.
If I do `prefersLargeTitles = false`, it works fine, no jumping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent hours trying to fix it thanks to the poor Apple documentation on `UIRefreshControl` but finally found a solution. You have to add your `refreshControl` in the `viewDidAppear` method, I was adding it on the `viewDidLoad` method:

```
    override func viewDidAappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        collectionView.refreshControl = refreshControl
    }
```